# opencv code does not detect the number of faces neither puts a circle around the face

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, face-detection

My code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);


    CascadeClassifier cascade, netCascade;

    double scale = 1;

    netCascade.load("/opt/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml");
    cascade.load("/opt/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml");


    //cap.open();
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"error opening video file"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
   
    while(1)
    {
        Mat img;
        cap>>img;

        if(img.empty())
        {
            break;
        }


        //Mat img1 = img.clone();

        vector<Rect> faces, faces2;
        Mat grey, smallImg;

        cvtColor(img, grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        double fx = 1 / scale;

        resize(grey, smallImg, Size(), fx, fx, INTER_LINEAR);
        equalizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);

        cascade.detectMultiScale(smallImg, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,30));

        
        cout<<"number of faces = "<<faces.size()<<endl;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = faces[i];
            Mat smallImgROI;
            vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
            Point center;
            Scalar color = Scalar(255, 0, 0); // Color for Drawing tool
            int radius;
            double aspect_ratio = (double)r.width/r.height;


            if( 0.75 < aspect_ratio && aspect_ratio < 1.3 )
            {
                center.x = cvRound((r.x + r.width*0.5)*scale);
                center.y = cvRound((r.y + r.height*0.5)*scale);
                radius = cvRound((r.width + r.height)*0.25*scale);
                circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
            }
            else
                rectangle( img, cv::Point(cvRound(r.x*scale), cvRound(r.y*scale)),
                        cv::Point(cvRound((r.x + r.width-1)*scale),
                        cvRound((r.y + r.height-1)*scale)), color, 3, 8, 0);
            if( netCascade.empty() )
                continue;
            smallImgROI = smallImg( r );


        }




        imshow("video",img);

        char c = (char) waitKey(25);
        if(c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

First open the laptop camera. Then capture video. then allocate mat frames.Then convert to grayscale image, resize it. Allocate a vector of faces, matching with xml file. Find the number of faces using face.size(). Print the number of faces(faces.size()) on command line using cout.Draw circles around face. But the number of faces is printed as 0 while I am sitting in front of it. I think it should print 1. Also, it does not draw circles around the face. Where am I doing mistake? When my face is close to the screen, it shows 2 circles around my 2 eyes sometimes, but not always. Sometimes, the faces.size() returns 3. How is this possible to have value 3. Why does not it draw circle always?

Comment: you are not detecting faces, netCascade is not used.

Comment: then what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

To detect faces, you must call `detectMultiScale` on face cascade classifier.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);


    CascadeClassifier face_cc;

    double scale = 1;
    face_cc.load("/opt/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml");


    //cap.open();
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"error opening video file"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        Mat img;
        cap>>img;

        if(img.empty())
        {
            break;
        }


        //Mat img1 = img.clone();

        vector<Rect> faces, faces2;
        Mat grey, smallImg;

        cvtColor(img, grey, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        double fx = 1 / scale;

        resize(grey, smallImg, Size(), fx, fx, INTER_LINEAR);
        equalizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);

        //cascade.detectMultiScale(smallImg, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,30));

        //detect faces
        face_cc.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces );


        cout<<"number of faces = "<<faces.size()<<endl;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            Rect r = faces[i];
            Mat smallImgROI;
            vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
            Point center;
            Scalar color = Scalar(255, 0, 0); // Color for Drawing tool
            int radius;
            double aspect_ratio = (double)r.width/r.height;


            if( 0.75 < aspect_ratio && aspect_ratio < 1.3 )
            {
                center.x = cvRound((r.x + r.width*0.5)*scale);
                center.y = cvRound((r.y + r.height*0.5)*scale);
                radius = cvRound((r.width + r.height)*0.25*scale);
                circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
            }
            else
            {
                rectangle( img, cv::Point(cvRound(r.x*scale), cvRound(r.y*scale)),
                        cv::Point(cvRound((r.x + r.width-1)*scale),
                        cvRound((r.y + r.height-1)*scale)), color, 3, 8, 0);
            }
            smallImgROI = smallImg( r );
        }

        imshow("video",img);

        char c = (char) waitKey(25);
        if(c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```